# Why isn't the location of my UITouch being logged? (Custom Keyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch

I am overriding the touchesBegan function of the main view in my KeyboardViewController and for some reason the location of the touch isn't being logged. Am I doing something wrong? 
 **Note:** This is not a game

```
   class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
            let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
            let location = touch.locationInView(self.view!)
            println("\(location.x)")
        }
}
```

Update 1: Adding a comment to the start of the function also results in nothing being called which means the function isn't being called at all. Do I have to add it in any way to my viewDidLoad func?

Comment: `Note: This is not a game`. Best. Disclaimer. Ever. :)

Comment: @akashivskyy hahaha didn't mean for it to sound so cryptic

Comment: is touch and or location returning nil?

Comment: @Kendel The whole function isn't even being called :( I tried adding a comment to the beginning of it (i.e. println("I am being called") and that doesn't show up either so I don't think it's touch/location returning nil

Comment: @cyril : make sure you are debugging you "iOS keyboard extension" and not the "iOS app" in which you embedded the extension .